# How to exclude null values from Count() function in reporting services 2005?

Tags: sql, reporting-services, visual-studio-2005

I am creating a report that has a pareto-like graph and a table of Order Types and how many units of each order type there are. The subset returned from the stored procedure that I am using includes a field called WorkItemId, and if that value is null that means that item isn't to be counted. How should I count Order Types in the report without including the values that have the null WorkItemId? Right now I am using the expression:

```
Count(Fields!OrderType.Value)
```

to count the each unit for a specific order type.

Thanks!

EDIT: **WorkItemId** is what cannot be null to be counted, **not** Order Type

Null values in WorkItemId are needed in other reports, so I can't just simply filter them in SQL.

Comment: Is it SQL issue or Visual studio 2005 issue?

Comment: Visual studio, I just need to find a way to count specific order types  with the constraint of the WorkItemId not being null (not in SQL).

Answer (score 8):

You can use something like

```
Sum(IIF(IsNothing(Fields!WorkItemId.Value),0,1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a where clause in your SQL clause :

```
 where WorkItemId is not null
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: The NULL value in WorkItemId is needed for other reports, is there any other way?

Comment: This aims to be used on the side of the database : The where clause is added into the SELECT SQL request.

Comment: I deleted my first comment, see the new one above.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out my own question...Again

Since the row in my table is already being grouped by order type I just needed to put

```
Fields!WorkItemId.Value
```

Into the Count function rather than OrderType, since Count() automatically disgards nulls.